# Jquery only runs when I set a break point on any line, or won't

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple form which sends name and email to my database. Jquery is listening to the form and when validated sends the data to form.php .

When I set a break point in firefox dev tools, form.php will be called with the correct data. Otherwise, what I THINK is happening, is that form.php gets called BEFORE jquery manages to send through any data (and this can be understood by the fact that only when I set a breakpoint does the first part of the code be read). I think something like this is happening [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) , I have read it but wouldn't know how to implement these solutions in my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#submit").on("click",function() {
var name = $("#Name").val();
var email = $("#Email").val();

if (name == '' || email == '') {
  alert("Please Fill Required Fields");
} else {
  $.post("form.php", {
    name1: name,
    email1: email
  }, function(data) {
    $("#returnmessage").append(data);
    if (data == "Thanks a lot!") {
      $("#form")[0].reset();
    }
  });
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to pass event in every function, that did it.

$(document).ready(function(event) {

$("#submit").on("click",function(event) {

```
event.preventDefault();

var name = $("#Name").val();
var email = $("#Email").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **event.preventDefault();** in your code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {

  $("#submit").on("click",function() {

    event.preventDefault();

    var name = $("#Name").val();
    var email = $("#Email").val();

    ...
```

Comment: Hi @ahsan i get an error saying 'event is not defined', and same problem as usual

Comment: Make it $("#submit").on("click",function(event). I have corrected the code above (see the 'event' added in the function parameters).

Comment: TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function

Comment: So, did it work ? If yes, please consider up-voting the answer. Thanks.